# Why is my Xbox 360 not working?

Tags: xbox-360

I have a 4 year-old Xbox 360. Until a few days ago, I could play the Xbox and it started normally.

But now, when I press the power button, this happens:

- The power button lights up green
- The cooling fan does not spin
- Nothing shows up on my TV
- It needs a *very* long time to boot up

Also,

- The Xbox is not connected to the internet
- I'm using [composite/RCA cables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector)

Comment: I improved the phrasing for you. Please fix it if I've screwed anything up. I still have some clarifying questions, though: what do you mean it takes a long time to boot-up? If there's nothing on your TV, how are you gauging whether it has booted up? What color are the three cables? It could be the red, green, and blue component cables with the additional red and white audio cables, or it might be the red, white, and yellow composite cables. Composite cables are sometimes called RCA cables.

Comment: Also, do you mean that it is unable to connect to the internet, or that you haven't even hooked it up to the internet?

Comment: @DCShannon No, i havent hooked it up to the internet

Comment: @DCShannon the colours are yellow, white, and Red

Comment: @DCShannon alright bro, i just relize its not the boot up... sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

If it was just no video, I would suspect a problem with the cable. You could try using a different cable and/or television.

However, if the fan isn't running, then it would seem like there's a more serious problem. Running the console without the fan could damage it further due to overheating.

Because of the potential for further damage, I would recommend [sending it to Microsoft for service](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/warranty-and-service/getting-your-product-serviced).